# Identify gaps in dates

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, powerpivot, powerquery

I have a table with 50000 records of workers. I am trying to identify the "first" start date for each worker. The first date should reset if the worker has been off assignment for at least 30 days.

I am comfortable with power query and power pivot if either helps solve this problem. I am not very comfortable with VBA but am not opposed to a solution this way this either.

Data

```
Unique ID   Order ID    Worker Start Date   Worker End Date
1   1   02/01/2016  03/23/2018
1   2   04/23/2018  04/25/2018
2   3   02/10/2014  05/15/2015
3   4   01/01/2013  05/02/2014
4   5   01/01/2013  05/01/2015
4   6   06/01/2015  10/28/2016
4   7   10/31/2016  07/31/2017
4   8   08/31/2017  04/22/2018
5   9   01/02/2017  05/05/2017
6   10  01/01/2013  12/31/2014
6   11  02/02/2015  01/31/2017
6   12  03/03/2017  04/22/2018
7   13  09/29/2014  09/29/2016
7   14  10/31/2016  03/02/2018
8   15  01/01/2013  05/04/2014
9   16  02/18/2013  05/20/2014
10  17  01/01/2015  03/31/2016
10  18  03/28/2016  03/03/2017
10  19  09/18/2017  09/18/2017
11  20  11/30/2015  02/12/2016
11  21  05/18/2016  07/29/2016
12  22  01/01/2013  11/14/2014
13  23  06/01/2015  08/27/2017
14  24  06/17/2013  02/08/2015
15  25  06/02/2014  11/30/2014
16  26  02/09/2015  06/12/2015
17  27  01/01/2013  12/23/2014
17  28  02/02/2015  12/22/2016
17  29  12/23/2016  12/21/2017
```

Expected Results

```
Unique ID   Expected Date
1   04/23/2018
2   02/10/2014
3   01/01/2013
4   08/31/2017
5   01/02/2017
6   03/03/2017
7   10/31/2016
8   01/01/2013
9   02/18/2013
10  09/18/2017
11  05/18/2016
12  01/01/2013
13  06/01/2015
14  06/17/2013
15  06/02/2014
16  02/09/2015
17  02/02/2015
```

Comment: What have you researched / tried so far, and what is the specific issue / error you need help with?

Comment: Are these records all one employee?

Answer (score 3):

First, create a custom column `Plus30` to make it easier to see what's happening.

```
= Date.AddDays([Worker End Date], 30)
```

Now we want a custom column that checks if the current row's `Plus30` occurs before the next row's `Worker Start Date`.

```
= Table.AddColumn(PrevisousStepName, "Custom",
      (C) => if List.Min(
                    Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type",
                        each _[Unique ID] = C[Unique ID] and
                             _[Order ID]  > C[Order ID])
                    [Worker Start Date])
             > C[Plus30] then 1 else 0, Int64.Type)
```

This will return an `Error` if there is no subsequent row for that `Unique ID`, returns `1` if the next row's `Worker Start Date` is less than that row's `Plus30`, and returns `0` otherwise.

At this point, I replaced the errors with an integer (I arbitrarily picked `-1`) and then filtered out all of the `1` values in the `Custom` column.

Once those are filtered, group the table by `Unique ID` and take the minimum over `Worker Start Date` for your `Expected Date` column.

Here is the entire M code where I loaded your data into a table `Table1`:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Unique ID", Int64.Type}, {"Order ID", Int64.Type}, {"Worker Start Date", type date}, {"Worker End Date", type date}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Plus30", each Date.AddDays([Worker End Date], 30), type date),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", (C) => if List.Min(Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each _[Unique ID] = C[Unique ID] and _[Order ID] > C[Order ID])[Worker Start Date]) > C[Plus30] then 1 else 0, Int64.Type),
    #"Replaced Errors" = Table.ReplaceErrorValues(#"Added Custom1", {{"Custom", -1}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Replaced Errors", each ([Custom] <> 1)),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filtered Rows", {"Unique ID"}, {{"Expected Date", each List.Min([Worker Start Date]), type date}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

---

Note that you can skip adding the `Plus30` column and just include that bit in the `Custom` column. To do this, replace `C[Plus30]` with `Date.AddDays(C[Worker End Date], 30)` in the formula.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this on my actual data and power query is just running in the background and gets locked up. I haven't received an error yet but its not running either. I will update later

Answer (score 1):

Your explanation is a little unclear to me butI think you mean you want the ***last*** start date, excluding periods that were followed by absence of 30 or more days?  And `Unique ID` is the employee?

If so, I would use simple worksheet formulas and AutoFilter, starting with adding a column with a formula to calculate number of days between "this end" and "the next start", something like this:

[image: img]

...in this example the formula in `E2` is:

```
=IF(A3<>A2,"",C3-D2)
```

Then AutoFilter or otherwise delete any rows where the number in column `E` is greater than 30.

This would give a result like this:

[image: img]

Note that there's an overlap on `ID #10` in your data.